# Python Chromedriver WinError 2 with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I get this following error in my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", 
line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried changing the PATH variable, changing the chromedriver path to no avail. Funny thing is that this error only happens sometimes, I have yet to find a pattern though. This is my chromedriver definition:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
chromepath = str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent) + r'\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath, options=options)
```

Comment: If you have the chromedriver.exe in path, I don't think you need to reference chromepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird that it only works sometimes. Set this to an absolute path and it should work fine.

```
chromepath = str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent) + r'\chromedriver.exe'
print (chromepath) #set the output of this below
driver = webdriver.Chrome("abs path here", options=options)
```

**Update:** Solution. Turns out I defined driver twice, removed one definition and it seemed to do fine. Unsure why it raised that particular error though.

Comment: So instead of putting the variable name, put the variable's value? I'll give it a shot but how does this change things?

Comment: Update: so if I understood correctly, then it didn't work.

Comment: This is weird indeed. The fact that it works sometimes is hard to comprehend. CAn you try something like this `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: I'll give it a shot, could it be possible that the exe is corrupt?

Comment: Could be that too

Comment: Tried both with no success. I've just noticed that it's also telling me that chromedriver its not in Path, despite it being in there.

Comment: You may have some courrupted path issues. You can try using Firefox and if its the same problem then we need to get the experts in

Comment: Update: I believed I solved it. Turns out I defined driver twice, removed one definition and it seemed to do fine. Unsure why it raised that particular error though.